# How can I use os.Name() in go?

Tags: go

I'm trying to use: https://golang.org/src/os/file.go?s=1472:1577#L35

by importing the "os" package and then running

```
f, err := os.Open("/tmp/dat3")
check(err)
name := os.Name(f)
```

I get `./main.go:29: undefined: os.Name`

Why? What am I doing wrong.

(Of course I know I *have* the name of the open file - but I'm curious why, I'm not able to call that function)

Comment: There is no 'os.Name' in the os package. What you need is to use get a `FileInfo` using `f.Stat()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Name` is a special function (`method`) defined on `File` struct. Means it takes `File` type as receiver and can be called using receiver instance (in your case `f`).

This should work

> `name := f.Name()`

Read more at :

https://tour.golang.org/methods/1

https://gobyexample.com/methods

Comment: Obviously...  I was trying that and I guess, some other error caught me off guard. Thanks, works.